# Does CouchDB have limits when setting up hundreds to thousands of Replications?

Tags: database, database-design, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm architecting a database to hold thousands of users using CouchDB. We need to synchronise data between the server-side DB and a device DB. [ couchDB <-> pouchDB ]

The only problem is that we will have hundreds to thousands of users, and we want to restrict the data synchronisation to only the data for that user.

This means that if we want 1000 users, we need 1000 replications set up for couchDB on the server side. Just wondering if this will push the limits of Couch, or if it's within it's designed capabilities. Or if there could be any performance deficiencies with this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why each user can't have there own database? If each user only needs to see there own data, then this would be a better strategy.

Comment: Yes this is one of the approaches we could take. However, we will have a server-side database and an on-device database. There will still need to be replication. If a document is changed for that user on the server, it will need to sync with device. If a document is changed on device, we will need to sync that with server. I think the points I'm making is that replication will need to take place regardless. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a yes or no answer to this as there are a number of factors that would have to be taken into account. You would really need to do some testing to see how well it scaled for you. In principle there is no reason a CouchDB server couldn't handle thousands of users.

How many and how frequently documents are created and modified will have a big impact on replication. The more there is to replicate the more work the server will have to do.

Running a filter function on replication so that each user only gets their documents will crease the load on the server. All changed documents will be checked for all replications. A per-user database model will avoid this extra work.

With a per-user database model you will also be able to scale out much more easily. If you find that you can comfortably host x users on a server, you can double that simply by adding another server.